# Load from nib file

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nib

I have an IB plugin that contains `myController`. I can set some properties of the controller in IB's Inspector. These properties are saved in the nib file but at runtime, myController doesn't init with these properties (they aren't read from the nib file).

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [NSBundle loadNibNamed:nibName] and -awakeFromNib methods?

Comment: Yes, I'm use -awakeFromNib. but this method don't help. Because it call ONLY when I drag myController from IB Library to the nib file window.

Comment: When I run the application -awakeFromNib method not call, and I can't use them for initialize myController

Comment: and what about -loadNib methods? they should resolve you problem. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html